# Facebook page notification pass_thread_control from chatbot to agent

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-page, facebook-chatbot, facebook-webhooks

Is there a way to create/add a notification on facebook page once a user is transferred via pass_thread_control from chatbot to agent?

The problem is that the agent isn't notified when the user is switched from chatbot to him and because of that, there is a possibility that conversation will be on hold/unanswered for a longer period of time...

Answer (score 0):

If you pass thread control to Inbox, there *should* be a notification sent to the Page Admins to see. Although that has not been completely reliable for me.

But you could set up your own notification system by also sending another message to your agent's account directly, letting them know that a conversation has been passed to them.

Comment: Currently, when the system passes conversation from chatbot to an agent, the agent receives notification only after user writes the next sentence. As far as I understood there is no automatic notification just for switching and that is why there is a possibility that user will have prolonged response time from agent. 
The problem with direct communication with agents is that I would need to customize code each time agent is added or removed from page since I can't get their IDs directly from API...

Comment: I am dealing with the exact same issue, and that is exactly how I will be handling it. The Facebook Page Admins will have to update a list of facebook IDs for who should receive the handoff notification. In some cases, it could be multiple people, and so my bot will send direct messages to each of the IDs listed after handing a conversation off to the Page Inbox. I do sometimes get notifications from the Inbox handoff, but always get obvious notifications when receiving a message, so that's more reliable. Facebook should really change this to notify about the handoff like a new message.